# Conteo de palabras en typeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, reactiveformsmodule

Necesito contar las palabras ingresados en un *textarea* en angular, he buscado mucho pero solo encuentro soluciones para *JavaScript* y se me complica al traducirlas a *TypeScript*. También me gustaría que no permita exceder un límite de palabras y que se muestre el total de palabras escritas en un *mat-hint*.

El código para del *textarea* es el siguiente:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <textarea matInput [formControl]="observations" id="observations" type="text" required></textarea>
  <mat-error *ngIf="observations.hasError('required')">Campo
    <strong>obligatorio</strong>
  </mat-error>
  <mat-hint align="end">{{observations.value.length}} / 256</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

En el *mat-hint* se muestra el conteo de caracteres pero requiero el conteo de palabras.

En el componente solo tengo el *FormControl*:

```
observations = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías tomar el valor del formulario y separlo por espacios para contar las palabras, te dejo un ejemplo para que te guíes

```
function countWords(): number {
  const words = observations.value.split(" ")
  return words.length
}
```